# Reading files from multiple directories in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I read my log files (cron_log, auth_log, mail_log, etc) using this config:

```
file{
path => '/path/to/log/file/*_log'
}
```

So I read my log files and check:

```
if(path) ~= "cron"  -----match--------
if(path) ~= "auth"  -----match--------
```

Now I have a directories like: `Server1 Server2 Server3`......In `Server 1` there are subdirectories: `authlog cronlog`.....Inside authlog there are subdirectories date wise (like `2014.05.26, 2014.05.27`) which finally contain log file for the day, which I have to parse.

So presently I was having one config file which use to read files using    `*_log`  and I use to run that config file and all log files present in `/path/to/log/file/*_log` were parsed.

Now I have to read from many directories (as explained above).

Will I have to write separate config file for each directory??

What's the best way to achieve this using logstash??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby globs interpret `**` as including all subdirectories.

So, for example, you could give the [`file` input](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/file) a path such as:

```
/path/to/date/folders/**/*_log
```

Comment: What if I want directory name (Server1, Server2) and subdirectory (cron, auth), so that accordingly I apply grok to match each file patterns respectively. Eg: For Server1 and cron type-----> Pattern1. So is there a way to grab those and apply conditionals on them later on???

Comment: Your `file` inputs can [apply a tag](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/file#tags); in the filter block, you can check tags using a [basic conditional](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/configuration#conditionals) like `if "foo" in [tags]`.

Comment: I want it on my Web interface, so that one can select first: Server1 then select cronLog. So a `field` or a `tag` must be added?

Comment: Either should work. A flat field might be a little bit easier to search for in the web interface.